# Gunicorn Failed to start Service (Unknown section 'Service'. Ignoring.)

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I am setting up Django Project on Digital Ocean with Nginx. I am getting error on journalctl -u gunicorn.socket this command. Got this Error

```
**

    root@vavaphysio:/var/www/html/sandbox# journalctl -u gunicorn.socket
    -- Logs begin at Mon 2020-01-06 03:17:11 UTC, end at Sat 2020-01-18 06:28:38 UTC. --
    Jan 14 12:08:43 vavaphysio systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket:6: Unknown section 'Service'. Ignoring.
    Jan 14 12:08:43 vavaphysio systemd[1]: gunicorn.socket: Unit has no Listen setting (ListenStream=, ListenDatagram=, ListenFIFO=, ...). Refusing.


    Jan 16 09:04:14 vavaphysio systemd[1]: Listening on gunicorn socket.
    Jan 16 09:36:44 vavaphysio systemd[1]: gunicorn.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
    Jan 16 09:53:47 vavaphysio systemd[1]: Listening on gunicorn socket.

**
```

Here is my gunicorn Socket file

```
**[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket
[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock
[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target**
```

Gunicorn Service File:

```
**[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target
[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html/sandbox
ExecStart=/var/www/html/sandbox/env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          sandbox.wsgi:application
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target**
```

Any Answer Please.

Answer (score 3):

with this settings you need to have file `/var/www/html/sandbox/sandbox/wsgi.py`

because you set `WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html/sandbox`

and in `ExecStart` you write `sandbox.wsgi:application`

so gunicorn try to enter to `WorkingDirectory` and find there `sandbox/wsgi.py`